# makes wishlist tree by category and subcategory

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, codeigniter-3

need to make category tree from wishlist added category and subcategory

my controller which gives the response.

```
public function index_get() {
    $this->check_authentication();
    $wishlist = $this->Wishlist_model->getByUserId($this->_user->id);
    $this->set_response([
        'status' => TRUE,
        'response' => $wishlist,
            ], REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
}
```

my model which fetches category and sub category as a tree perfectly but if i have added only subcategory into my wishlist then it is not showing because its parent category not present into wishlist table. how to solve this

```
public function getByUserId($id) {
    $categories = $this->getWishlistCategory($id,1,0); // userid/type/order
    $subCats = $this->getWishlistCategory($id,2,1);
    $this->mapCateogires($categories, $subCats);
    return $categories;
}

private function mapCateogires($categories, $subCats) {
    $data = array();
    foreach ($subCats as $item) {
        $data[$item->parentid][] = $item;
    }
    foreach ($categories as $item) {
        $item->childs = isset($data[$item->id]) ? $data[$item->id] : [];
    }
}
private function getWishlistCategory($userid, $type,$order) {
    $query = $this->db
            ->select("W.id as wishlishid, W.userid, W.type, W.itemid as id,W.created, C.name, C.icon, C.order,C.parentid,C.hasChild")
            ->from("wishlist as W")
            ->join("categories as C", "W.itemid=C.id",'LEFT')
            ->where("W.userid", $userid)
            ->where("W.type", $type)
            ->where("C.order", $order)
            ->get();
            return $query && $query->num_rows() ? $query->result() : [];

}
```

this is my actual result

```
{
"status": true,
"response": {
    "categories": [
        {
            "wishlishid": "20",
            "userid": "24",
            "type": "1",
            "id": "1",
            "created": "2018-01-22 12:32:47",
            "name": "Audio, Video, Electronics",
            "icon": null,
            "order": "0",
            "parentid": null,
            "hasChild": "1",
            "childs": [
                {
                    "wishlishid": "23",
                    "userid": "24",
                    "type": "2",
                    "id": "15",
                    "created": "2018-01-22 12:32:47",
                    "name": "Air Conditioners",
                    "icon": null,
                    "order": "1",
                    "parentid": "1",
                    "hasChild": "1"
                }

            ]
        },
        {
            "wishlishid": "21",
            "userid": "24",
            "type": "1",
            "id": "2",
            "created": "2018-01-22 12:32:47",
            "name": "Beauty, Health & Personal Care",
            "icon": null,
            "order": "0",
            "parentid": null,
            "hasChild": "1",
            "childs": []
        }
    ]
}
}
```

but i have added a subcategory into my wishlist which is not displaying because it parent category not present in wishlist items. if parent category not present in wishlist table fetch from category table and show it as a tree.

**My wishlist table structure:**

[image]

**My category table structure:**

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the actual result and the expected result? also your data structure

Comment: @Riyenz i am editing

Comment: @RAHULPRAJAPATI how are you linking between two tables

Comment: there is single category table